# A contradiction of product topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $X\times Y$ be their 
product. The product topology on $X\times Y$ is the topology generated by the 
basis $B = \{U\times V | U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y\}$. 
Since $X=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is a basis on $\mathbb{R}_{fc}$, thus open, so $X\times X$ must be open in $\mathbb{R}_{fc}^2$; On the other hand, $X\times X$ cannot be open in finite complement topology because its complement is not finite, i.e. is not a finite set like $\{(a,b), ...\}$; it is "line complement" not "point compliment". contradiction?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}_{fc} \times \mathbb{R}_{fc} = \mathbb{R}^2_{fc}$?

Comment: What is contradicted then?

Comment: Let $X=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. We can't write $X\times X$ as $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(a,b), ...\}$. So, $\mathbb{R}_{fc} \times \mathbb{R}_{fc} \neq \mathbb{R}^2_{fc}$. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly, what you have is instead the "line complement" topology, where every open set must be the complement of a finite set of vertical and horizontal lines (viewing $\Bbb R^2$ in the conventional manner).

Comment: So finite complement topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not same as the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ resulting from  
$\mathbb{R}_{fc} \times \mathbb{R}_{fc}$? In other discussion, I saw they are same! If I know a clear proof/disproof of this question, I can find out the answer the the original question.

Comment: Is $(\mathbb{R}_{fc} \times \mathbb{R}) \cup (\mathbb{R}_{fc} \times \mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^2_{fc}$ ? But, $\mathbb{R}_{fc} \times \mathbb{R}_{fc} \neq \mathbb{R}^2_{fc}$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the last comment, but your first comment is correct, the product of $\mathbb R_{fc}$ times itself is not the finite complement topology on $\mathbb R^2$.